# Complex vector space with a complex structure is a real vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space with a (linear) complex structure $J$.
Further assume that the vectors $u_1,...,u_n$ form a basis of $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$.
Then the vectors $u_1,Ju_1,...,u_n,Ju_n$ form a basis of $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

(Edit: $J:V\rightarrow V$ is any linear map with $J^2=-id$.)

---

It is clear that both the sets ${u_1,...,u_n}$ and ${Ju_1,...,Ju_n}$ are linearly independent. But so far I was not able, neither with linear combinations nor with inner products, to show that the whole set of vectors forms a basis.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear to me. Usually, a complex structure is a linear map $J \colon V \to V$ with $J^2 = -id$, where $V$ is viewed as a *real* vector space here. This turns $V$ into a complex vector space via $(a+bi)\cdot v := a \cdot v + b \cdot J(v)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and $v \in V$. Conversely, if $V$ is a complex vector space to begin with, then $J(v) = iv$ defines a complex structure on the real vector space $V$. It seems to me that you're working with the second possibility? But then the linear independence should be straightforward.

Comment: I am considering the second case and yes the map $V\rightarrow V;\; v\rightarrow iv$ defines such a $J$. But $J$ does not need to have this form, right? It could for example also look like $J(v)=-iv$. In both cases the claim is true...
But I am not given such an explicit choice of $J$, but only that it satisfies the relation $J^2=-id$, surely there lots of them and just from this the claim isn't obvious to me.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. In the second case, $J$ is diagonalizable, since the minimal polynomial of $J$ divides $X^2+1 = (X+i)(X-i)$. Hence you can write any $u_j$ as the sum of two eigenvectors w.r.t. the eigenvalues $+i$ and $-i$, respectively, say $u_j = u_j^+ + u_j^-$. Does this help?

Comment: So up to a change of basis, $J$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $\pm i$ and this let's us reduce the problem to cases in which I know the claim is true, namely $Ju_k=\pm u_k.$

This is helpful, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that there exist $a_1, \ldots, a_n, b_1, \ldots, b_n$ satisfying 
$\sum_{k} a_ku_k+\sum_{k} b_kJu_k=0$.
Since $u_i$'s are complex basis of $V$, you get $a_k+jb_k=0$ for all $k$.

Comment: What exactly is your lowercase $"j"$ ?

(I have edited my question and described what $J$ is... note that this is in general not just the complex unit $i$.)

Comment: I mean complex unit $i$ for $j$.
What do you mean by ``$u_1, \ldots, u_n$ form a basis of $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$''?

Comment: Every vector $v\in V$ can uniquely be written as a linear combination $v=\sum \lambda_k u_k$, where $\lambda_k\in\mathbb{C}$ .

Comment: In that definition, you regard $V$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.
This is possible because you have $J$. See the comment of Marktmeister.